# How do I use the rsync command correctly

Tags: local.xml, migration

I am migrating a customer site.  I have made a copy of it and placed it in a subdirectory of the root.  So just below the prod site.  I know that I can use the rsync command to make sure all files are the same in both directory's, but I am unclear as to the correct usage.  Also I believe there is a way useing the --delete option to keep it from syncing the local.xml file.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not specifically Magento related but more general server help.

Comment: Then where would I post it?

Comment: Normal stackoverflow or maybe http://serverfault.com/

Comment: If my answer solves the problem, maybe we can migrate the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the vote to close is appropriate, but it's used commonly enough for Magento deployments.

Try this:

```
rsync -avPzL --exclude='app/etc/local.xml' ./path/to/local/root/ user@remote.com:/path/to/remote/root
```

Where the `exclude` argument can be used multiple times, here we use it to specifically omit `local.xml` from the process.

You can optionally use `--dry-run` to test the transaction. The `avPzL` options you can see the manual for details, but they represent my most preferred option set when syncing code.